# Failing Cluster Resources Over Using Command Line

Tags: sql, windows, sql-server-2008, powershell

Is anyone aware of the commands required to complete the following:

1. Fail over a Cluster Resource from one Node to another Node within a Windows 2008R2 / SQL Server 2008 R2 Cluster
2. Pause a Node within a Cluster

I'm aware of how to do this through the GUI but not through Power Shell or Command Prompt. I've tried googling but unfortunately have been unable to come across anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to import [`Cluster Module`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619744%28WS.10%29.aspx) for `PowerShell`. Once you do, follow the steps in [this](http://mssqltrek.com/2012/08/16/how-to-failover-the-cluster-group-in-windows-server-20082008r2/) article.

Comment: Your answer would be even more helpful if you quoted the relevant steps from the article you referenced, since that article may or may not be available a year from now.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, absolutely. We'll fix that shortly.